# Session in to function, not getting set

Tags: php, session

i have a index page, where i can send the user to another url, the user can comment here, when he comments, he is sent to insert_comment.php, if all is succesfull, this gets set:

```
 $success = "Your comment has been added";
 $_SESSION['success'] = $success;
```

If i echo it afterwards, its set and all is fine

now i re-direct the user to the same URL

```
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/post/?post=". $url_from); // send back
```

this url calls this function

```
<?php 
fetch_for_inside($_SESSION['success']); // I pass the success session to the function
unset($_SESSION['success']); // unset
?>
```

All the other content is re-created, from within the function, and then i have this within the function

```
if (isset($success_session)) {

   echo '
             <div class="info">
               '. $success_session .'
              </div>
        ';
};
```

This is within the function, and the function does get

```
 function fetch_for_inside($success_session)
```

as a parameter, yet the variable is empty?

I do

```
<?php session_start() ?>
```

on http://mydomain.com/post/?post=". $url_from

and i do it inside the function

Comment: Have you tried removing the second `session_start();` from `fetch_for_inside`?

Comment: I have, does not work

Comment: But it stil gets it twice, since its the same page that is reloaded, could that be the issue?

Comment: As in

`session_start();`

`fetch_for_inside();`

`if (isset($success_session))` should return false

User submits

`session_start()`

`fetch_for_inside();`

`if (isset($success_session))` should return true

Answer (score 1):

Variable $_SESSION is not set before you start session. So make sure to call

```
<?php session_start() ?>
```

once before you call fetch_for_inside($_SESSION['success']).

There's a short article covering basics of a session in PHP [here](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions.htm)

Also a great way to track weird behavior of your scripts is to use IDE for PHP with debugger, like [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html#howDebuggerWorks) with Xdebug

Comment: Do i have to set it before i start the session ?

isnt it start_session(); and then $variable = $_SESSION(['something'])